# Sales bar chart for five stores

Tags: c++

I have created this program asking 5 companies to enter their sales for the day. Seems to be working correctly. What I can not figure out is how to get the chart to appear after the all 5 companies have entered in their sales. This is the code I have so far.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int sales = 0;
   int store = 0;
   float stars;

for (int store = 1; store <= 5; store++)
{ 
   cout << "Enter today's sale for store " << store << ":";
   cin >> sales;


   stars = sales/100;
   cout << "SALES BAR CHART:" << endl;
   cout << "(Each * = $100)" << endl;
   cout << "Store" << store << ":";


   for (int y = 0; y < stars; y++)
   {
 cout << "*";

   }

cout << endl;
}


system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store each of the store's values in an array so you can print them out later.  If you want it to be dynamic, you can dynamically allocate an array:

```
int stores = 5;
int* stores_stars = NULL;
stores_stars = new int[numberOfStores];
```

Then after you have assigned each of the stores values, you can loop through each element of the array and print out each store's stars with that loop you've written.

If you don't want to use arrays, or haven't been taught, you can just use separate variables and use multiple if statements, but I recommend you use arrays.

---

**Since you can't use arrays** (Not a big fan of badly written homework)

You will need to use multiple variables then.  You can declare 5 variables to store each of the stars

```
int storeStars1,storeStars2,storeStars3,storeStars4,storeStars5;
```

And assign each one based on the value of store in your loop

```
if (store == 1)
    storeStars1 = //Put your value here
else if (store == 2)
    //You can fill in the rest ;)
```

Then you can just copy that loop 5 times for each of the storeStars variables.  Better yet, put that loop in a function, and call that function 5 times.

Comment: Only thing is we cant use arrays. I can not use what I have, or I would have to separate all of the variables. I have to still use for loops

Comment: Just curious, there is no way to do so without having to create multiple variables? I understand what you are saying, just curious if i could do it without all these variables

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but I can't think of one.  Normally I would just do this with an array which is far simpler.  You can make use of the STL and have it automate the process, but that really is an over-engineering of a fairly simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is reasonable, often one doesn't know up front how many data points are available in these contexts.

The standard way is to use STL with a vector to store the data and then loop through using an iterator to produce the graph. You might consider separating the code that draws a single 'bar' of the graph into a new function to avoid the rather ugly nested loop.

There are very few real world situations where an array is a practical solution and as such I consider this a well engineered solution.

Comment: unfortunately vectors have not been covered yet in the class and we are only suppose to use what we have learned

Comment: It's basically a dumb question then - you can make the five variable solution much more elegant by having a single function to grab the data from the user and another function to print a bar. Go look ahead at the STL vector code - sometimes weak teaching just holds you back.